# Spring generic abstract controller and interface GET/DELETE methods mapping

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

Spring boot 2.2.7.
Lets imagine having the next project structure:

Generic repository interface:

```
public interface IRepository<T> {
    Optional<T> get(Long id);
    List<T> getALl();
    T save(T t);
}
```

…its implementation:

```
@Component
public class IntegerRepository implements IRepository<Integer> {
    @Override
    public Optional<Integer> get(Long id) {
        return Optional.of(10);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Integer> getALl() {
        return Arrays.asList(10,20,30);
    }

    @Override
    public Integer save(Integer integer) {
        return integer;
    }
}
```

Generic abstract controller class:

```
public abstract class AController<T> {

    private IRepository<T> repository;

    public AController(IRepository<T> repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public Optional<T> get(Long id) {
        return repository.get(id);
    }

    public List<T> getAll() {
        return repository.getALl();
    }

    public T post(T t) {
        return repository.save(t);
    }
}
```

Controller interface:

```
@RequestMapping("/integers")
public interface IntegerController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{id}")
    Optional<Integer> get(@PathVariable Long id);

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    List<Integer> getAll();

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    Integer post(@RequestBody Integer t);
}
```

…and its implementation:

```
@RestController
public class IntegerControllerImpl extends AController<Integer> implements IntegerController {
    @Autowired
    public IntegerControllerImpl(IntegerRepository repository) {
        super(repository);
    }
}
```

Why Spring doesn’t map controller’s `get()` and `getAll()` methods but `post()` do?

```
2020-05-16 09:44:51.347 TRACE 5437 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping :     c.a.s.c.IntegerControllerImpl:  {POST /integers}: post(Integer)
```

UPD. I did some research and found that if controller subclass would override GET/DELETE methods (PUT and POST are working well), it will work as expected. So it seems that those HTTP methods are not supported to inherit such behavior from superclass due to generics... However, maybe later I'll open an issue with this case on spring MVC GitHub repo.

```
@RestController
public class IntegerControllerImpl extends AController<Integer> implements IntegerController {
    @Autowired
    public IntegerControllerImpl(IntegerRepository repository) {
        super(repository);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Integer> get(Long id) {
        return super.get(id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Integer> getAll() {
        return super.getAll();
    }
}
```

Log output

```
2020-05-16 13:54:12.843 TRACE 5914 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : 
c.a.s.c.IntegerControllerImpl:
{GET /integers/{id}}: get(Long)
{GET /integers}: getAll()
{POST /integers}: post(Integer)
```

[This Example GitHub](https://github.com/averude/spring-generic-controller-issue)

Comment: You didn't show enough of your controller body to be able to tell. (And note that in real code, Spring Data can handle two-thirds of this for you automatically.)

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- Thank you for reviewing the problem. As for your suggestion about Spring Data, I know about that. I intentionally omit it in this case in order to simplify the understanding of my question. Controller's body is in the AController class.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some extra research, debugged Spring and found that in this particular case RequestMappingHandlerMapping bean doesn't resolve methods which don't have in signature pure generic return type. Can't say for sure whether it's reflection fault/feature or Spring handler's logic. Nevertheless, I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/25090) on Spring repository.